# QuickSight bill confusion: cost incurred even though no reader users' activity, no author user

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing, amazon-quicksight

I have signed up for QuickSight with the following subscription and usage:

- Enterprise edition
- Per reader pricing
- 8 readers
- 2 admins
- 0 author

The 60 day trial period has expired on May 31. Since the middle of May until today (6. June) there has been absolutely no activity on my QuickSight account. Today I saw in the bill for June: QuickSight costs (so far) $3.97 for 0.165 User. I could not figure out what corresponds to this cost.

What I understood from my subscription plan is:

- for each reader: $0.30/session, max $5.00/month
- for each author: $24.00/month or $18.00 x 12/year

Can anybody please explain the above cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Today I saw in the bill for June: QuickSight costs (so far) $3.97 for 0.165 User.

If we do the math, `3.97 / 0.165 = 24`.

> for each author: $24.00/month

So you are being charged for an author user. Quicksight provides one author user for free every month. So you are being charged for the second admin on top of the free one in your QS account.

Note that an "admin" user is still charged as an author, as they have full authoring capabilities and other administrative privileges.

Here's a screenshot of our AWS billing dashboard for this month:  [image: AWS Billing Dashboard - Quicksight] We don't have any authors in this account as of now - just two admins and a reader. One admin user is in the free tier and is not being charged at all ($0.00 in the bill). The second admin in our account is being pro-rated (4.6/0.192=24) at $24 per month.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It has really explained my case.

Comment: I've deleted 1 admin user and now wait to see if the bill still increases.

Comment: Today I've contacted AWS support and their answer confirmed the answer above from @nonbeing: "By default, one (admin/author) user is always free to have on the QuickSight account. Any additional users would incur cost and Amazon QuickSight users are charged monthly. The user charges are displayed in daily increments in case a user is added to the account partway through the month. For example, you add a user on the 15th of the month, you will only be billed for that user from the 15th to the end of the same month."

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the update @Mako